# Sending Image to Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a web API which takes image as input and saves the photo in some directory.
From web application controller I will get image and I need to send image to web API.
How to achieve this?
Both web API and web Application are created in Dot net core 2.1

Below are the code details.

**Web API code:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageTestController : ControllerBase
{
    //Image upload
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> ImageUpload([FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists("actualpath"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("actualpath");
                }
                using (FileStream filestream =   System.IO.File.Create("actualpath" + file.FileName))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(filestream);
                    filestream.Flush();
                    return file.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Unsuccessful";
        }

    }
}
```

**web application controller**

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SavePhoto(IFormFile fileParameter)
     {
            //In fileParameter i will recieve the image
         and i need to send this to Web API
     }
}
```

**.cshtml: containing kendo UI upload control**

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                     .Name("files")
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" } )
                      .Multiple(false)
                      .Async(a => a
            .Save("SavePhoto", "Sample")
            .AutoUpload(true)
            .SaveField("fileParameter")

            ))                       
</div>
```

In the view, after image is taken from user, it will hit to SavePhoto method in Sample controller. From controller I need code to send image to API. Finally I should be able to save the photo.

Comment: Do both controllers belong to the same solution?

Comment: Yes, same solution but different projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's much better to refactor your `ImageTestController` and `SampleController` to share a same `ImageUploader` Service .

```
// an interface that describes uploading image 
public interface IImageUploader{
    Task<string> UploadAsync(IFormFile file);
}

// upload an image to local file system (I just copy your code)
public class LocalImageUploader : IImageUploader{

    public async Task<string> UploadAsync(IFormFile file){
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists("actualpath"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("actualpath");
                }
                using (FileStream filestream =   System.IO.File.Create("actualpath" + file.FileName))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                    filestream.Flush();
                    return file.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Unsuccessful";
        }

    }
}
```

And now register the service by:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton<IImageUploader,LocalImageUploader>();
}
```

Finally, change your controller as below :

```
public class ImageTestController : ControllerBase
{
    private IImageUploader _uploader;

    public ImageTestController(IImageUploader uploader){
        this._uploader = uploader;
    }
    //Image upload
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> ImageUpload([FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
        var result= await this._uploader.UploadAsync(file);
        return result;
    }
}

public class SampleController : Controller
{
    private IImageUploader _uploader;

    public SampleController(IImageUploader uploader)
    {
        this._uploader = uploader;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SavePhoto(IFormFile fileParameter)
    {
        //In fileParameter i will recieve the image
        var result=await this._uploader.UploadAsync(fileParameter);
        return new JsonResult(new { });
    }
}
```

---

By the way, I don't think it's a good way to return a magic string in `UploadAsync()` method. I prefer to creating a new `Result` class.

---

**[Update] : How to use a HttpClient to post an image to Web API**

1. Create a uploader client service as below :

```
    public class HttpImageUploader 
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public HttpImageUploader(HttpClient client)
        {
            this.httpClient = client;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var req= new HttpRequestMessage();
            req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            // you might need to update the uri 
            req.RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api/ImageTest/");
            HttpResponseMessage resp = null;
            using(var fs=file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                var imageStream=new StreamContent(fs) ;
                imageStream.Headers.ContentType= new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);
                // because your WebAPI expects a field named as `file`
                form.Add( imageStream,"file", file.FileName);
                req.Content = form;
                resp = await this.httpClient.SendAsync(req);
            }
            return resp;
        }
    }
```

2. register this image upload service :

```
services.AddHttpClient<HttpImageUploader>();
```

3. Change your web action method as below:

```
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        private HttpImageUploader _uploader;

        public SampleController(HttpImageUploader uploader)
        {
            this._uploader =  uploader;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SavePhoto([FromForm]IFormFile fileParameter)
        {
            var resp = await this._uploader.UploadAsync(fileParameter);
            return Json(resp); // now you get the response.
        }
    }
```

4. As a side note, you probably need to change your `ImageTestController::ImageUpload` as below :

```
using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create("actualpath" + file.FileName))
using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create("actualpath/" + file.FileName))
{
    ...
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my requirement is different. 
My requirement is, from view i will take image and then it will hit web application controller, 
from this controller i need to call Web api and save image. Actual Image saving logic will be in web api.
Challenging part is how to send image data to web api from web application controller.

Comment: @SohailAkhter If I understand it correctly, what you're trying is to create a `HttpClient` and send the image file to anther WebAPI action method, right? If that's the case, it's rather easy.  But before I update my answer, could you please explain why you prefer to sending image in that way instead of sharing the same uploading service?  As far as I know, it is not that efficient.

Comment: It is because all logic will be in Web API and other applications consumes this Web API. 
Can you tell how to send image file to another API using HttpClient?